# How to store arrays in XML tags?

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am having 3 arrays

```
 $IPAddress
 $VMName
 $HostName
```

What i would like to do is each value in these arrays should be stored in corresponding XML entries.

For ex. All these 3 arrays are having around 10 entries.

First entry in all the three arrays should be stored in first XML tag, second entries in second XML tag and so on. My XML file should be looks like below.

```
<VM>
  <IPAddress>IPAddress[0]</IPAddress>
  <VMName>VMName[0]</VMName>
  <HostName>HostName[0]</HostName>
</VM>

<VM>
  <IPAddress>IPAddress[1]</IPAddress>
  <VMName>VMName[1]</VMName>
  <HostName>HostName[1]</HostName>
</VM>
```

How to store the values into XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pattern = '
<VM>
  <IPAddress>{0}</IPAddress>
  <VMName>{1}</VMName>
  <HostName>{2}</HostName>
</VM>
'
$elements = 0..($IPAddress.Length-1) | % { $pattern -f $IPAddress[$_], $VmName[$_], $HostName[$_] }
```

And now simply wrap the `$elements` in a root and store in a file.